# java.io.FilePermission exception - Read from jar file?

Tags: java, applet

Hi I have a Java Applet which plays a file of my local file system. When I embed the Applet in a web page I get a io.FilePermission Exception. I understand that the only way round this is to get my Applet signed which I don't wish to.

How would I go about read the file from it's own jar file?, As I understand this will be the best way.

Thanks for any help guys.

Heres my code

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PlaySoundsApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener{
  Button play,stop;
  AudioClip audioClip;

  public void init(){
  play = new Button("  Play in Loop  ");
  add(play);
  play.addActionListener(this);
  stop = new Button("  Stop  ");
  add(stop);
  stop.addActionListener(this);
  audioClip = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "clip.wav"); //Exception here trying to read from the www root instead of jar file

  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
  Button source = (Button)ae.getSource();
  if (source.getLabel() == "  Play in Loop  "){
  audioClip.play();
  }
  else if(source.getLabel() == "  Stop  "){
  audioClip.stop();
  }
  }
}
```

Updated code:

```
  public class PlaySoundsApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener{
  Button play,stop;
  AudioClip audioClip;

  public void init(){
  play = new Button("  Play in Loop  ");
  add(play);
  play.addActionListener(this);
  stop = new Button("  Stop  ");
  add(stop);
  stop.addActionListener(this);
  try {
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("resources/clip.wav"));
    Clip audioClip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    audioClip.open(audioInputStream);
} catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {System.out.println("Unsoported Error");} 
  catch (IOException e1) {System.out.println("IO Error");} catch (LineUnavailableException e) {System.out.println("Line unavailable Error");}
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
  Button source = (Button)ae.getSource();
  if (source.getLabel() == "  Play in Loop  "){
  audioClip.play();
  }
  else if(source.getLabel() == "  Stop  "){
  audioClip.stop();
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the exception from?

Comment: I take it is's from 
audioClip = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "clip.wav");

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 3) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Comment: *"..I understand that the only way round this is to get my Applet signed which I don't wish to."*  Bad news.  Even sand-boxed applets need to be digitally signed in this day and age, in order to have a reasonable chance of working.  But getting an applet resource by `File` will not work when deployed in any case, so use an `URL` instead.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that one up Andrew. Looks like the new security update in Java is just a barrier to my project.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
URL url = getDocumentBase();

AudioClip audioClip = getAudioClip(url, "music/JButton.wav")
```

Project sturcture

[image]

Comment: With that (using your post) an IO Exception is caught and get NullPointerException at `audioClip.start();`

Comment: What are you doing. Using == to compare the string. Its very bad.

Comment: use `equals()`. I don't know what are you doing. I have to post a complete code.

Comment: .equals() as it tests by value :) not reference

Comment: I think it might be something to do with the try catch statement?

Comment: I have updated my post. Please copy it and let me know once copied. I will delete it.

Comment: OK have coppied. now FileNotFoundException: resources\clip.wav (syetm cannot find path...)

Comment: please confirm you have copied clip.wav file under resources folder.

Comment: Yes it is in the resources folder which is in the root of my project along with bin and src. I did created the resources folder myself if that makes any diffrence. Also am running it from the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: please confirm under bin folder. Do you have bin/resources/clip.wav?

Comment: Yes I now have bin/resources/clip.wav and it works but not when embedded on a web page, button does nothing.

Comment: Yes thanks allot! you have any idea why it won't work when embedded on website?

Comment: if put in the buttons actionListener, it cannot get static reference for non-static class getClass();

Comment: I have added a new approach. Please have a look.

Comment: Works in Eclipse AppletViewer but not when embedded in web browser. is really bugging me. Take it you still use the same tags etc `<applet code="PlaySoundsApplet.class" archive="Sound_Clip2.jar"`. They are in correct directories, the applets runs in browser but buttons do nothing.

Comment: Applets and files mix like oil and water (poorly).  Applet resources should typically be loaded via URL.