# How am I supposed to draw an image from my Java Applet?

Tags: java, image, applet

I am not sure how to fully express this but, I have probably gone through 10 pages of Google links on this topic and not one of them has helped me solve my issue.

I thought it would be simple enough, I was just trying to add an image to the `paint` function of my java applet, like any other shape, but this has turned out to be a nightmare for me.

The problem is that every time I try to run the `drawImage` function it keeps saying **Access Denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "Image.jpg" "read")**. Yet, none of the tutorials mention this at all, all they ever say is that I should do the following:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

Image img;

//These would go in the paint function
img=getImage(getDocumentBase(),"/Image.jpg"); //I have tried without the slash too

g.drawImage(img,20,20,this);
```

This is all they do and it works for them, but it just won't work for me. Other methods are far too complex for the sake of just adding an image, and even when I go through the toil of doing those it keeps giving me the "Access Denied" message. There's also the method of "signing" it, but I really don't think that's going to help given all that I have tried, so I am afraid it might just be another wasted endeavor. None of the tutorials even tell you to have your applet signed.

I have the image in the "build" (also called bin) folder together with the classes.

The program seemed to run when I included the entire file path, but even then the image did not display. That is not to mention I can't really include the complete path from my own computer because then it wouldn't work when I actually send it to another person.

Please, I just want to know why it doesn't work for me yet seems to work perfectly for others. That, and if there's a way around this.

This is an example of what I am doing:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JavaProject extends JApplet
{
    Image img;

    public void init()
    {

        img=getImage(getDocumentBase(),"/Image.jpg");

    }



    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

        g.drawImage(img,20,20,this);

    }


}
```

This is my HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> My First Web Page </title>
</head>

<body>
    <applet code="JavaProject.class" width="400" height="500">
    </applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your method `getImage()` do?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/applet_image.htm check it out

Comment: getImage() is supposed to get the url of the class I think, something of the sort. I am new to this, so I can't explain it more technically.

Comment: @user3127499 That's exactly what I've been doing. Media tracker doesn't make it any better

Comment: Is there a chance that you are running your applet from file system and not via HTTP?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is from the file system. The URL of the applet goes something like: file:///C:/ etc. I am not sure how to run it via HTTP, the book only mentioned that we had to write the .html on notepad and run that.

Comment: So, try to run this over HTTP and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

According [JApplet java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getImage%28java.net.URL%29) method getImage(URL url, String name) should have two parameter: URL-link to picture and String name.

Is method `getDocumentBase()` returnig an URL-link?

Comment: Ops sorry, I misreaded that javadoc: There should be first absolute URL and then relative locatioN just as you've done getImage(getDocumentBase(), "/Image.jpg".

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if *the image in the "build" (also called bin) folder together with the classes.*

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class JavaProject extends JApplet {
    Image img;

    public void init() {
        img = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "images/222.png");
        // Please ensure that 222.png is placed under bin/images folder directly
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        update(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 20, 20, this);

    }

}
```

---

Try with HTTP URL first

```
URL myURL = new URL("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a94613cea642e6e9e2105867bc2e103e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");
img = getImage(myURL);
```

If you are using Eclipse under Windows then have a look at below screenshot:

[image]

Please have a look at below post to get some understanding about it.

- [java.io.FilePermission exception - Read from jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988516/java-io-filepermission-exception-read-from-jar-file?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: It still gives me the AccessControlException error...sigh, I never knew how troublesome it would be to get an image going

Comment: How are you running your applet? From eclipse or as HTML page.

Comment: I have added one more link in my post. Please have a look and read comments as well.

Comment: I am running it as an HTML page

Comment: No dice thus far, I am using NetBeans by the way, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Is there no help with this post?

Comment: I don't think it helped my issue as I keep getting the access denied message. Tell me, does such a program work for you? The one I posted I mean. I want to know why it is that MINE doesn't work yet to others it does.

Comment: Yes it works. Can you try to access images from any HTTP URL?

Comment: Also, I don't know how to use run the program through appletviewer, I am opening it by clicking the html file (running the code on NetBeans does nothing), not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Someone else mentioned HTTP, but I don't know how to go about doing that. Google doesn't provide any good results that explain how to run it through HTTP and not the file system.

Comment: Oh I tried accessing images from an HTTP URL, it denied me access as well.

Comment: Can you try with my sample code first with HTTP URL?

Comment: Yes I did, gives me access denied except this time it says acess denied "java.net.SocketPermission" and not "java.io.FilePermission". It's like I don't have permission for anything.

Comment: Then its the problem with your system only. May be settings of Firewall or Network or ...

Comment: Hmm any idea how to fix that then?

Comment: Alright I tried the sample code, same socket permission error

Comment: Could you show the code that you have for this? Maybe I am doing something wrong. I eliminated the "package" line for example, since it is an applet I am trying to make. I have the html file in my build folder and that's where I am running it from.

Comment: I don't have a friend readily available, so I am not sure I can really test it on another computer

Comment: add your HTML file in your question itself along with the folder structure.

Comment: @ Braj Need 10 reputation to post pictures

Comment: share it using any link and mention link in your post.

Comment: Space.gif would be the image I was trying to display at the start of the question.

Comment: Try with `<param name="permissions" value="sandbox" />` for more info have a look at [Manually Coding Applet Tag, Launching Without JNLP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html)

Comment: Try to access [this URL](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/papers/Java-tutorial/getStarted/applet/example/Hello.html) and let me know the result.

Comment: It yet gives me the access denied message. Truly, I appreciate that you have aided me this far. Do you think I ought to try the getResourceAsStream method?

Comment: It said "Hello World", no image though

Comment: I have added it in my post.

Comment: What does it mean that I can run it but you can't? Also, I'd like to send you the code somehow, I am not sure I feel comfortable about posting it online as it is a project

Answer (score 0):

You must start by understanding that an Applet, unless signed, may not read from the file system. It must use either classpath resources or things fetched from the same place it was fetched from. You have to decide which of these applies to you. If the image is a fixed image, you can put it in your classpath as a resource, and use Class.getResourceAsStream. If it's a different image every time, you'll have to use HTTP.

Comment: will `Class.getResourceAsStream` work in case of Applet? I think `getDocumentBase()` is designed for this purpose to access files form the class-path.

Comment: That's one of the methods I saw when I was browsing on how to place images. Thing is, I have no idea how to implement this into my code

Comment: If course getResourceAsStream works. Just put the image into the jar file in a suitable location and it will be there.