# How can I draw an image in the paint function of my Java Applet? (Update)

Tags: java, applet

Earlier I asked a question on how I could manage to draw an image with my applet:

[How am I supposed to draw an image from my Java Applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590755/how-am-i-supposed-to-draw-an-image-from-my-java-applet/23590867?noredirect=1#comment36208761_23590867)

The update is that my Java Applet runs from the file system and I think that might be giving me the error I am getting.

I would truly appreciate it if one would take the time to view my question. If you don't want to read the other question a quick recap is that I am getting the "Access Denied" message whenever I try the `g.drawImage` function. A user brought up the fact that it is because I may be running my applet from the file system, how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How am I supposed to draw an image from my Java Applet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590755/how-am-i-supposed-to-draw-an-image-from-my-java-applet)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if *the image in the "build" (also called bin) folder together with the classes.*

I have posted an answer in your last question itself.

- [How am I supposed to draw an image from my Java Applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590755/how-am-i-supposed-to-draw-an-image-from-my-java-applet/23591492#23591492).